# Domain name slash user name redirect to PHP page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I would like to find a way for users to be able to type their username after my domain name to access their public profile page.
For example, if you type `youtube.com/username` it shows that user's channel page. The resulting page is the same as `youtube.com/user/username`.
So with my website, I have `mydomain.example/users/profile.php?name=username`
It's a bit more complicated, with PHP and variables and subdirectories and everything... I would like that same page to display when I type `mydomain.example/username`
I really have no idea where to start with this, but I suspect it would be something in the .htaccess file, which I do have access to.
Thanks for any help!

edit: sorry this is a few days old, I've been having some other troubles and I haven't been able to test it until now. Anyway, it isn't working...
Just to recap, I want `mydomain.example/username`
to filter to
`mydomain.example/users/profile.php?name=username`

Thanks..

edit2: I found this also on stackoverflow... [link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231067/htaccess-rewrite-for-query-string) i tried tweaking that, and what was mentioned here a few days ago... but it still won't work. Any ideas?
I also keep finding pages that recommend the strategy this guy used: [link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136442/php-and-htaccess-redirection-rewriting-yoursite-com-user-phpusernamexyz-to-you) but it looks like that would cause more problems than it's worth.
Any ideas?

Comment: I've created a "404 handler" page that takes the username like that, looks up the user's info in DB, then redirects to their profile.. so the /tim page never exists but redirect's to Tim's profile.

Answer (score 3):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^user/(.*)$ profile.php?name=$1 [NC,B,QSA]
```

Comment: May want to make it `[QSA,NC]` so that existing query string items will get added.

Comment: I added B to escape the backreference and removed the leading / because he referred to htaccess (per-directory rules).

Comment: I admit I just changed the first RewriteRule google came up with. So yeah, thanks ^^

Comment: Shouldn't there be any kind of RewriteCond as a condition here?